# how to update a visual basic application without reinstalling

Tags: .net, vb.net, installation, updates, uninstallation

I have a simple form with a button when clicked says Hello.

Code as follows:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox("hello")

End Sub
```

End Class

I installed it on my machine and now I was wondering how would i write updates to it without reinstalling the whole thing?

Comment: How do you mean you installed it?.. Did you create an installer package for the app? Self-Updating apps are generally custom implementation unless you've opted for a clickonce deployment.

Comment: I created an installer packager through vb

Comment: Look at ClickOnce deployment, it automatically handles updates.

Answer (score 1):

You could roll your own updater app which checks on an ftp site / web site for files which are newer. But it will have to be a separate app because you won't be able to update the currently running exe without stopping it first. Also the location of files can be an issue depending on permissions etc.

A better option as HansPassant suggested is to use ClickOnce deployment. This handles all the above for you and allows you to force your application to check for updates before it runs so you know you have the latest version out there.

[Here is a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get you started

Answer (score 0):

If YOU KNOW that the updates have no problems with the various environment (e.g.: no change in framework, DB, etc, etc) and you are just testing and work in a "controlled" place then you can simply replace the executable file.

But I certainly  prefer ClickOnce :-)

Once you set it up it works so nicely that the time to update the application is just a little more than replacing the executable... and you are much more safe